# Xpath element with common parent

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to find the 'comment' node where the 'name' node == 'package 3'. Previously I was using `rpc-reply/blah/blah-blah/information/package-information[3]`, but I'm looking for a more robust method which filters on the 'name' and returns the associated 'comment'.

I did some googleing and found the 'Kaysian method' might be what I was looking for, however I could not apply/understand it.

To phrase my question in another way, the below might clarify what I am after:

`SELECT comment WHERE name = 'package 3' FROM rpc-reply//package-information`

```
<rpc-reply>
<blah>
    <blah-blah>
        <information>
            <package-information>
                <name>package 1</name>
                <comment>44565545</comment>
            </package-information>
            <package-information>
                <name>package-2</name>
                <comment>6859887</comment>
            </package-information>
            <package-information>
                <name>package 3</name>
                <comment>5548845</comment>
            </package-information>
            <package-information>
                <name>package 4</name>
                <comment>548878</comment>
            </package-information>
        </information>
    </blah-blah>
</blah>
</rpc-reply>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the `package-information` element whose name is `package 3` and then go down to the comment:

```
/rpc-reply/blah/blah-blah/information/package-information[name='package 3']/comment
```

Comment: Is there a method to skip right down to package-information, such as:
`rpc-reply//package-information[name='package 3']/comment`

Comment: @user3770935 yes, `//` finds any descendant

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```css
//name[contains(text(), 'package 3')]/following-sibling::comment
```